# Partition table, each partition on different disk on my HDD

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table that I would like to partition in MYSQL 5.5. That I know how to do, but what I also need is to specify a disk for each of my partitions.

For example, I would like to put:

- P01 in c:\
- P02 in d:\
- .......

and so on.

I'm currently using this statement: (which doesn't fulfil my requirements, but works perfectly)

```
ALTER TABLE transaction_transaction
PARTITION BY RANGE (effectiveDate_)(
  PARTITION p01 VALUES Less Than (1288562400000),
  PARTITION p02 VALUES Less Than (1293660000000),
  PARTITION p03 VALUES Less Than (1298757600000),
  PARTITION p04 VALUES Less Than (1303855200000),
  PARTITION p05 VALUES Less Than (1308952800000),
  PARTITION p06 VALUES Less Than (1314050400000),
  PARTITION p07 VALUES Less Than (1319148000000),
  PARTITION p08 VALUES Less Than (1324245600000),
  PARTITION p09 VALUES Less Than (1329343200000),
  PARTITION p10 VALUES Less Than (1334440800000),
  PARTITION p11 VALUES Less Than (1339538400000),
  PARTITION p12 VALUES Less Than (1344636000000),
  PARTITION p13 VALUES Less Than (1349733600000),
  PARTITION p14 VALUES Less Than (1354831200000),
  PARTITION p15 VALUES Less Than (1359928800000),
  PARTITION p16 VALUES Less Than (1365026400000),
  PARTITION p17 VALUES Less Than (1370124000000)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
PARTITION p0
  VALUES LESS THAN (1288562400000)
  DATA DIRECTORY ="C:\\foo\\bar"
  INDEX DIRECTORY ="C:\\foo\\baz",
...
```

Mind that this needs NO_DIR_IN_CREATE to be off

As user963602 points out, this doesn't directly work on windows due to a MySQL bug, see my comment for a workaround

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in windows as in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations.html):"On Windows, the DATA DIRECTORY and INDEX DIRECTORY options are not supported for individual partitions or subpartitions (Bug #30459)."

So i think you ment on Linux?

Comment: To be honest, I just missed this bug (I don't use Windows). A workaround would be to create your partitions on one disk, then stop the MySQL server, move the files to their desired locations, then do mklink  <filename as original> <new target path>

Comment: am using InnoDB Engin, I don't think that it's possible to seperate data files from _ibdata1_ , Have you tried this before on Innodb engine?

Comment: @user963602 though this is an old answer it bears mentioning for future readers that the innodb_file_per_table option will allow you to have data files separate from ibdata1.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB SE won't support the specifying the disk/mount :(