# What do you think about my DB architecture?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I think I am not doing the best thing I can in my designed DB architecture.

Also I am using MySQL;

I have 2 main tables: IMEIs and user;

IMEIs structure:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| imei    | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

users structure:

```
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pass  | varchar(2000) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, I will join these tables, meaning each user can have multiple IMEI, and I think this structure is just fine.

The problem is where I get some data for each IMEI, and I want to save them.
I can't save all IMEIs data in one table, since that will be huge table. Think that each IMEI sends a data every 30 seconds. It could fill up my tables very soon, as that would be 120(per hour) * 24 * 30 * 1000 = 86,400,000 which is quite huge for a table. 
I want to create individual tables for each IMEI with name `data_{IMEI}`, but then that can make many tables.

I don't have any clue on how much MySQL can be efficient with multiple tables, but here we are talking about 1000 (a good estimate by me) tables.

This is not a problem for now, but after 6 months or a year, I may run into problems. I have to foresee my design for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that one table will be (too) huge?

Comment: I have a mysql table with 1.6 million records in it and queries to it are very fast, even with multiple joins to other tables.

Comment: It's not clear to me where the join will be happening. Is there a column in common between IMEIs and users?

Comment: @eggyal there will be a data for each IMEI every 30 seconds. This results in a total of 2,880,000 record in a day for 1000 IMEIs. I think of this as huge.
@Robbert thanks. I think my case is more huge than this.
@catfood The join happens between IMEIs and users. `SELECT * FROM IMEIs INNER JOIN users ON users.id = IMEIs.user_id` but that is not the problem. The problem is to save data for each IMEI every 30 seconds.

Comment: So, the temporal data pertaining to each IMEI should be stored in a separate table which has a foreign key to the IMEI table. For how long do you plan to retain this data? You could partition this table horizontally to improve query performance. Incidentally, editing the question to mention this requirement might be an idea..

Comment: @IanNelson Yes. Data for each IMEI is to be there like forever.

Comment: Forever? That's a mighty long time! Approximately how many bytes of data are you storing every 30 seconds for each IMEI?

Comment: @IanNelson Somehow like forever. Each data received creates a varchar(20), 4 varchar(10) and a timestamp (probably varchar(30)) in a row. When I think of this, it can be quite large on disk, too! These situations will not happen now, but after 6 months or a year, I could run into problems. I am foreseeing problems for that time.

Comment: For now, I will go for partitioning (which seems to work just fine with my case). I have to think about a way to move my old data to another database periodically. Maybe not all data is not needed at a time, but I have to keep them. Maybe moving them to a partition could be fine, or even moving them to another database. I have to check them out, but for now, I accepted an answer. Thank you All guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't save all IMEIs data in one table, since that will be huge table.

If there is something relational databases a good at, that's managing huge number of rows in a single table. Assuming you use indexing properly, performance will scale **logarithmically** (i.e. the time to do various operations will raise much slower than the amount of data).

What you tried to do is in effect a form of (horizontal) **partitioning**. Fortunately, you can [let the DBMS do that for you](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html), while still keeping one "logical" table and avoiding the complications your "manual partitioning" would entail.

Partitioning can help with performance, and can also help in situations when a single table is so huge that it outgrows the capacity of a single physical drive, by [putting different partitions on separate physical drives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820437/533120)<sup>1</sup>.

---

*<sup>1</sup> [Unfortunately](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html): "The DATA DIRECTORY and INDEX DIRECTORY options have no effect when defining partitions for tables using the InnoDB storage engine.". I suggest you use a more capable DBMS than MySQL if your table becomes that huge*

Comment: What about having like 50 partitions? Better than having multiple tables?

Comment: @thelastblack Any number of tables >1 will prevent the DBMS from enforcing the uniqueness of primary key and complicate any child foreign keys you might need. In that sense, 2 partitions are better then 2 tables and 50 partitions are (way) better than 50 tables.

Answer (score 5):

`I can't save all IMEIs data in one table, since that will be huge table.`

Why do you think this? One big table is often better than a database full of tables. If each table is the same, seriously consider making a big table.

Then, if it goes slow, you can go about partitioning it (into PHYSICAL seperate parts), but keeping the logical table as one table.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil ;)

Comment: I don't know about partitioning. My most experience with MySQL was with web and php. I had designed DB in MSSQL which had many rows, but I don't know about MySQL vs. MSSQL things. A good link may help me.

Comment: OK, I read something about partitioning. Another question: Is having, say, 50 partitions better than multiple table?

Answer (score 2):

You can, and should, save all the IMEI's in one table. Storing large amounts of structured data is a databases job.

By creating a table for each IMEI you're making the database harder to interact with and more complicated.

In general. Database layout should be relatively static and the data stored should be what changes.

Comment: I mentioned in my other comment that each IMEI will have data every 30 seconds. So better to have them all in on table?

Comment: Yes even so. Having them all in one table will perform much better than attempting to spread them across thousands of tables.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, I would suggest introducing a link table and having a many-to-many relationship between IMEIs and Users. What happens if/when an IMEI is transferred to another user?

In answer to your original question, a single table with a row for each IMEI is the way to go, don't contemplate dynamically creating a table per IMEI.

Comment: IMEI is not to be transferred, and it is not for a phone. It is used for a device with SIM card.