# Does partitioning improve performance when your table doesn't fit in memory?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, insert, partitioning

So I have a table that gets a relatively good insert performance ( 2500-3000 rows inserted per second ) but once it gets bigger than my allocated memory (2gb) it slows down 15 times... The worst part is that it will eventually grow to around 20gb...

It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `slots` (
 `customerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `queueid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `item_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable1` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable2` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable3` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable4` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable5` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable6` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `variable7` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `variable8` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `variable9` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY `queueid` (`queueid`, `customerid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `customerid` (`customerid`,`orderid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25883472 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The reason I believe that happens is because I check if the insert isn't duplicated(INSERT IGNORE) so MySQL server needs to check all of the unique-index values - and since they no longer fit in the memory, it has to use the much slower disk I/O.

I've decided to partition my table -> I've made 30 ranges that split the 50 million rows into 30 parts (by range of the customerid field).

But still when I hit the memory limit, it slows down.

Are there any tricks to keep inserts high? This guy (http://www.slideshare.net/bluesmoon/scaling-mysql-writes-through-partitioning-3397422) seemed to use partitioning with great success. My problem is that my data comes in not sequential order so I can't simply append the row to the last position in the index ( sometimes it gets inserted in the middle of the table, sometimes at the beginning, sometimes at end etc. )

How would you construct the keys to get the highest possible insert/select performance? It seems to me that there is some obvious thing that I could do (besides getting more RAM) to keep the speed high.

If any MySQL genius is reading this - kindly please spend a minute and help me with this.

Comment: Why is the data being inserted in order? Would you be able to restructure your table and app to use the table optimized for writes, and then use indexes to optimize some limited number of reads?

Comment: So you are saying I should drop the auto-increment field? Wouldn't that decrease performance? Should I drop this field? This table will get frequent selects once I finish inserting the data ( and also a smaller, continous stream of inserts of new data ) I think creating another read-optimized copy of this table would eat a lot of RAM which I already have little of...

Comment: If it's an auto-increment, and the increment step is always deterministic and positive, wouldn't that imply that data is always being inserted at the end--or at least, the most recent partition? Dropping auto-increment would mean you have to have some other way of determining your primary key (and ensuring its uniqueness across parallel inserts), but shouldn't change your insert behavior, unless you have some kind of sorting method applied to the table.

Comment: Would dropping the auto-increment field and making the customerid field primary-key (one column instead of a two-column composite) improve select/insert performance? I will test this just wanted to know if this is possible ( since it will take at least 6 hours to check )

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure, which is why I don't want to post this as an answer. The best answer is always to test with your particular use case and data sets. Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried reducing disk contention by paritioning your table over several disk drives. At some point you will hit the memory barrier and disk contention will become a major bottle neck. See this link for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820160/partition-table-each-partition-on-different-disk-on-my-hdd